# Problemas com Rodapé

Tags: html, css, angularjs

estou tendo problemas com meu rodape em uma pagina que contem uma lista, qu na qual vou adicionando e ela crescendo. O problema é que está criando duas barras de rolagem no site e nao estou conseguindo resolver.
Segue a lista e o css.

```css
.footer {
 background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width:100%;
    height: 60px;
    position:fixed;    
    bottom:0;

}
```

```html
 <table id="lista-compras" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Assunto</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="topico in topicos | filter:search" class="comprado-{{ topico.comprado }}">
        <td><strong>{{ topico.assunto }}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>{{ topico.descricao }}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>{{ topico.grau }}</strong></td>
        <td><strong>
          <a href="
```

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode postar o link onde possamos ver o problema?

Comment: https://forum-alldispor.c9users.io/index.html#/topicos consegue ver?

Comment: tenta usar overflow:hidden no #main do css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue resolver esta questão da segunda barra de rolagem facilmente. No seu arquivo `style.css` que está neste link:

```
https://forum-alldispor.c9users.io/views/css/style.css
```

Na linha 18 que inicia com `html, body {`

remova desta classe a linha 21, remova isto:

```
height:100%;
```

Ou seja, você substitui isso (inicia na linha 18):

```
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height:100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

Por isto:

```
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Deu certinho, valeu!